# python output object not iterable

Tags: python, class, oop, iterator, iterable

I couldn't see a relevant answer on here that I could understand. I have some code that outputs what I thought would be a list I could iterate over but cannot.

***code:***

```
class freqList():
    def __init__(self, startFreq, stopFreq, skip):
        self.startFreq = startFreq
        self.stopFreq = stopFreq
        self.skip = skip

    def __iter__(self):
        pass

    def listFreqs(self):
        return list(range(self.startFreq, self.stopFreq, self.skip))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}, {}, {}'.format(
            self.startFreq,
            self.stopFreq,
            self.skip)


    def __str__(self):
        return 'instance object of frequency list, startFreq:{},stopFreq: {},skip: {}'.format(
            self.startFreq,
            self.stopFreq,
            self.skip)


print('\n'*4)
listy = freqList(  1000, 5000, 1000)#range cannot use floats, only ints
print(listy.listFreqs())

print('listy type:', type(listy),'\n')

listy_iter = iter(listy)
print('listy_iter type:', type(listy_iter),'\n')
```

***Desired output***

When I instantiate the class I want it to return an iterable list-like object.

***Tried***

I have seen mention of **next** which needs to be overridden but I don't know what that means, I am new to OOP and have only just got my head around **init**, **str** and **repr**.

Comment: Well your `__iter__` method just returns None.  If you make it do something like `for x in self.listFreqs(): yield x`, then you can do `for item in listy: ....` in your main code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a small adjustment in your class

```py
class freqList():
    def __init__(self, startFreq, stopFreq, skip):
        self.startFreq = startFreq
        self.stopFreq = stopFreq
        self.skip = skip
        self._freqs = list(range(self.startFreq, self.stopFreq, self.skip))

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._freqs)

    def listFreqs(self):
        return self._freqs

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}, {}, {}'.format(
            self.startFreq,
            self.stopFreq,
            self.skip)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'instance object of frequency list, startFreq:{},stopFreq: {},skip: {}'.format(
            self.startFreq,
            self.stopFreq,
            self.skip)
```

If you look I changed the list to be created within `__init__` and stored in an attribute. Then the listFreqs will call this attribute to show the entire list.
The iterator creation happens on `__iter__`, where self._freqs is wrapped with the magic `iter()`.

If you have your list defined in the `listFreqs`, then it will recompute everytime you call this method. Additionally, the class won't know what it is until the method is called, so it cannot create an iterator on it.

Answer (score 1):

In python once you instantiate a class what you get is a object. So instead try this

```py
listy_iter = iter(listy.listFreqs())
```

This will return the list which is the return type of the function `listFreqs` of class `freqList()`

Now `listy_iter` will have a list

Answer (score 1):

Your `__iter__()` method actually has to return an iterator. Like this:

```
class freqList():
def __init__(self, startFreq, stopFreq, skip):
    self.startFreq = startFreq
    self.stopFreq = stopFreq
    self.skip = skip

def __iter__(self):
    return iter(range(self.startFreq, self.stopFreq, self.skip))

def __repr__(self):
    return '{}, {}, {}'.format(
        self.startFreq,
        self.stopFreq,
        self.skip)


def __str__(self):
    return 'instance object of frequency list, startFreq:{},stopFreq: {},skip: {}'.format(
        self.startFreq,
        self.stopFreq,
        self.skip)


listy = freqList(  1000, 5000, 1000)

for l in listy:
    print(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try elaborating about your issue. 
From my understanding below is what your in search of

```
  def __iter__(self):
      iter_list = list(range(self.startFreq, self.stopFreq, self.skip))
      for i in iter_list:
           yield i
```